# ASP.NET Core Deployment Profiles

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, deployment, blazor-webassembly

Having built a Blazor (hosted) application in development environment in blissful ignorance of the challenges of deployment, I now come to my first attempt at deploying.

My intention is to deploy to my local machine on IIS as a 'staging' environment before publishing a 'production' environment to the web.

My first attempt resulted in a snag relating to connection strings, which I believe is because my development settings had used integrated security, but the staged deployment is using IIS Application Pool identity, which does not have the SQL permissions.

Fine.  So I think my next step is to create an appropriate appsetting.json file for 'staging'.

What I *think* I understand:

1. When 'publishing' the appropriate appsetings.<environment>.json file will be merged with the root appsettings.json file and become the deployed appsettings.json file.
2. The launchSettings.json file sets the <environment> under one of the 'profiles'.

What I can't get to the bottom of:

1. How, when I'm publishing from Visual Studio, do I tell it which 'profile' to publish with?

Or have I misunderstood something else?

**UPDATE:**

I now see that on project properties > Debug tab, I have the opportunity to create an additional "Profile" and set the Environment Variable for ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to "Staging".  From there, I guess I can create an appsettings.staging.json file.

So, I think my question now is:

Do I have to go to the 'Debug' tab and select the profile I want to use BEFORE publish?  And then change it back for when I'm doing more work in development?

Comment: Usually, a staging environment isn't really a 'separate' environment, and you should not use a separate `appsettings.staging.json`. Staging slots are just exact copies of your production app and they run under production appsettings if they are meant to be deployed to production. Traffic to the 'live' app will get (partially) redirected to your staging app. It's what's called a blue-green deployement.. - at least when it's deployed to a cloud hosting provider. As for your selecting the run profile, I see it in my Publish screen whenever I use that to deploy something from Visual studio.

Comment: Thanks, Dennis.  Perhaps 'staging' is the wrong word?!  Basically, its an environment running on my local machine on IIS outside of the development environment.  I use the same local DbSvr but a different database from Dev so need different conn strings, hence a different appsettings.  Re, the profile, I don't see it on my Publish screen but have since found out how to edit the 'pubxml' file behind to specify the 'EnvironmentName'.